# Javascript create objects with both new and without new + inheritance

Tags: javascript, inheritance, constructor, factory

I am creating a library in javascript that create javascript objects.

1. How can I write the interface of the library so that their users can
   create such objects both WITH and WITHOUT new? (I saw a lot of answers that propose constructors that auto-call itselfs with new if they were not invoked with new in first place but no the other way around).
2. Can we use new with Object.create? For example:
   let dog = new Object.create(animal);
3. How to provide inheritance

To illustrate with code, how do you write the functions Animal and Dog below so that the following expressions are valid:

```
let animal = new Animal(); // valid
let animal = Animal(); // valid also, we should return the same object
let dog = new Dog(); // valid, dog inherits/shares functions and properties from Animal.
let dog = Dog(); // valid also, same case as in previous call.
```

Thank you so much.

Comment: If a constructor returns an object, `new` will have no effect. Perhaps look into that. [**Example**](https://jsfiddle.net/z3vqx9bx/1/).

Comment: Chapter 3 of [**this book**](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596517748.do) will probably be of some help.

Comment: So can I for instance directly return Object.Create? and it will work (including inheritance) with and without new?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do :

```
function Animal(name) {
  if(!(this instanceof Animal)) {
    return new Animal(name);
  }

  this.name = name;
}

Animal.prototype.walk = function() { console.log(this.name, 'is walking...'); };

function Dog(name) {
  if(!(this instanceof Dog)) {
    return new Dog(name);
  }

  this.name = name;
}

Dog.prototype = Object.create(Animal.prototype);
Dog.prototype.constructor = Dog;

var animal = Animal('John');
var other_animal = new Animal('Bob');

var dog = Dog('Blue');
var other_dog = new Dog('Brutus');

animal.walk(); // John is walking...
other_animal.walk(); // Bob is walking...

dog.walk(); // Blue is walking...
other_dog.walk(); // Brutus is walking...

console.log(dog instanceof Animal); // true
console.log(dog instanceof Dog); // true
```

Comment: You have to set the constructor of `Dog` to `Dog` after `Dog.prototype = Animal.prototype`. And don't forget to put in some semicolons.

Comment: I think you set `Animal.prototype.constructor` to `Dog` because you didn't clone the prototype.

Comment: I'm wondering if there's a way to set `name` on `Animal.prototype` so that `Dog` inherits it .

Comment: @StevenLiekens I think `Animal.call(this, name);` in the Dog constructor (replacing `this.name = name;`) will do it

Comment: That still ends up assigning to `this.name` which is different from `Dog.prototype.name`. Maybe that's the correct behavior though.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142300/discussion-between-steven-liekens-and-babarconnect).

Comment: Thank you. Is it possible without using new at all in the implementation of Animal and Dog? What happens ofor instance if someone does "new Object.Create()"?

Comment: That is invalid code. `Object.create` returns an object that is never a constructor.

Comment: So how to detect if there was a new before calling Object.Create?